# Import data from few csv files to database in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

What is the best way to import data from few csv files in Spring Batch? I mean one csv file responds to one table in database. 
I created one batch configuration class for each table and every table has its own job and step. 
Is there any solution to do this in more elegant way?

Comment: if you do not need sophisticated mapping and/or to apply business rules, you can look into the import capabilities of your database, e.g. for mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a variety of ways you could tackle the problem, but the simplest job would look something like:

- `FlatFileItemWriter` reader with a `DelmitedLineTokenizer` and `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper` to read the file
- Processor if you need to do any additional validation/filtering/transformation
- `JDBCBatchItemWriter` to insert/update the target table

Here's [an example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-csv-file-to-database/) that includes more information around specific dependencies, config, etc. The example uses context file config rather than annotation-based, but it should be sufficient to show you the way.

A more complex solution might be a single job with a partitioned step that scans the input folder for files and, leveraging reference table/schema information, creates a reader/writer step for each file that it finds.

You also may want to consider what to do with the files once you're done... Delete them? Compress them?